# Learning python and dealing with erros

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

```
class User():

    name = ""
    last_name = ""
    sex = ""

    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name, self.last_name, self.sex = kwargs.get('name'), kwargs.get('last_name'), kwargs.get('sex')

    def introduceMyself(self):
        print("My name is {0.name} {0.last_name}, nice to meet you".format(self))

usuario = User(name ='Marcelo', last_name = 'Mendonça', sex ='M')`
usuario.introduceMyself()`
```

> in the def of the methode i am getting this errors and i dont know why:

Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Any]", variable has type "str")

Unexpected keyword argument "name" for "User"

Unexpected keyword argument "last_name" for "User"

Unexpected keyword argument "sex" for "User"

Comment: `__int__` should be `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, `__int__(self, **kwargs)` should be `__init__(self, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Omg, thank you Youri. I am new to python, so sorry for the dumb questions